# Could not build Google Function from GO source

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform

Trying to use Google Functions with GO language and everything working OK locally - I could run the function and all seems to be working

Once I deploy function from command line I receive an error at Google Build:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3, message=Build failed with status: FAILURE and message: functions.local/app/main.go:18:2: import "github.com/my/app" is a program, not an importable package. For more details see the logs at https://console.cloud.google.com/cloud-build/builds;region=....
```

I am using go 1.21.4

I have a function containing file like so:

```golang
package handlers

import (
     ...
     ...
    "github.com/my/app/data"
    "github.com/my/app/utils"
    "github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-go/functions"
)

func init() {
    functions.HTTP("handleFunc", IncomingCall)
}

func IncomingCall(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
...
...
}
```

and actually a `main.go`:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"

    // Blank-import the function package so the init() runs
    _ "github.com/my/app/handlers"
    "github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-go/funcframework"
)

const DEFAULT_PORT = 12789

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Started")

    // logger := utils.CreateLogger()

    port := os.Getenv("PORT")
    if len(port) == 0 {
        port = string(DEFAULT_PORT)
    }

    if err := funcframework.Start(port); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("funcframework.Start: %v\n", err)
    }

    log.Println("Done")
}
```

What could be a program ? How I can fix this error:

`import "github.com/my/app" is a program, not an importable package"`

`go.mod`:

```golang
module github.com/my/app

go 1.21.4

require github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-go v1.8.0

require (
    cloud.google.com/go/functions v1.15.1 // indirect
    github.com/cloudevents/sdk-go/v2 v2.14.0 // indirect
    github.com/google/uuid v1.3.0 // indirect
    github.com/json-iterator/go v1.1.10 // indirect
    github.com/modern-go/concurrent v0.0.0-20180228061459-e0a39a4cb421 // indirect
    github.com/modern-go/reflect2 v0.0.0-20180701023420-4b7aa43c6742 // indirect
    go.uber.org/multierr v1.10.0 // indirect
    go.uber.org/zap v1.26.0 // indirect
)
```

deploy command:

```
 gcloud functions deploy temp01 `
    --gen2 `
    --runtime=go121 `
    --region=europe-west6 `
    --source=. `
    --entry-point handleFunc `
    --trigger-http `
    --allow-unauthenticated
```

Comment: Do you have a go.mod file? If so, can you post it?

Comment: @CoreyOgburn added

Comment: You didn't follow the instructions, Alex.  You can't import `main` in a Google Function.  https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/create-deploy-http-go

Comment: Hi @erik258 - what do you mean "import main" - sorry - I don't understand. Could you answer in section below ?

Comment: It's all spelled out quite well in the document I linked.   Did you read that document?  Do you have specific questions about that document?

Comment: Sorry - I could not see any difference in my code and code in linked document. I moved main.go file from root folder to \cmd and now error is: "Step #2 - "build": 2023/11/15 19:48:47 Unable to extract package name and imports: unable to find Go package in /workspace/serverless_function_source_code."    So - could you just answer in section below ?

Comment: What's you entrypoint in your commend line? It must be IncomingCall

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find an answer to my question thanks to @erik258. The answer is not directly addressed in the document you linked, but I found it here: [Write Cloud Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing). There is a specific section on project structure organization. My mistake was that I initially set up the project as a regular GO project with `main.go` in the root folder. After moving the file to the suggested `\cmd` folder and rearranging the imports in `main.go`, it started working!

Thank you again: [@erik258](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1726083/erik258)